# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 on Live server Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.1` Its working perfectly on localhost. But when I try to login it returns the error,

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

When I remove `CSRF` token by commenting `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',` In `app/Http/Kernal.php`. But after this it redirect to login page itself without session.

I also checked `config/session.php`,

```
// session.php

<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
];
```

The `storage` and `autoload` folders are also writable.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Make sure you have the right session domain in session.php

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja How do I check ?

Comment: nvm its not the probleme, u have the {{ csrf_field() }} under ur form right?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Yes. Its working perfectly in localhost

Comment: wait the probleme is on localhost or  no?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja The issue is only on live server

Comment: try to change the 'domain' => null,  to 'domain' => and your domain for exemple, 'domain' => www.website.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111266/discussion-between-vinod-vt-and-achraf-khouadja).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the login form in view:

`@csrf`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax, look at the manual about the csrf_field token setup:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 0):

This error may generate because of many issues.

So far I found 3 cases only:

1. **Invalid Content-Type** of input Form.
2. External(from outside) **DB changes**.
3. **Missing CSRF token** input.

And the possible solutions are:

> Change form's content-type,
>
> Refresh migrations(or somehow handle theDB table values to work), and
>
> Include a csrf token.

This is from my experiece in Laravel v5.2, you may have a different cause.